# calculate offset position

Tags: html, raphael, slideshow

I'm trying to implement linear carousel with js and HTML5.
The problem that I need to calculate the offset (dx) from the current touch in the screen.
my code:

```
document.addEventListener('touchmove', function(event) {
   event.preventDefault();
   var touch = event.touches[0];
    posx=touch.pageX;
posy=touch.pageY;
},false);
```

For Example: current posx is 365 and i moved 1px right. then my dx will be 1 and so on...

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Save the current x and y position to global variables on every change and calculate the difference between the last and current values before overwriting the values again.

Comment: Thanks, I tried it. Now I have another problem, How can I save the last position without overwrite it again?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean... In order to save the last value, you HAVE to overwrite it each time, AFTER calculating (and processing or saving) the difference values.

Comment: Lets say that my last pos is: 350 and my new pos is 351, so the dx is 1. that's simple. but now in your approach I'll store the new pos in the last pos (351) var and the subtract next new pos (352) from the last pos and still get 1. In my approach if I'll save the first last pos (350) and only that and I'll substract each new pos from the last one. so i'll know the exact offset from my last pos...

Comment: Check if the variable is already set, and only set the variable on change if it is not.

Comment: Nope! :) But as I've come across this term several times today, I'll really have to look into it! ;)